# Is there a method in Python that gets distribution residues in the analysis of linear regression?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

Is there a method in Python that gets distribution residues in the analysis of linear regression? I want to use array of this values for analysis. Yes, I can calculate, but maybe there is a method in some python libraries that can get me these values of residues?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @AlexBerg I use this code to build Linear model Regression:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model=sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
prediction=model.predict(X)
model.summary()`
```

from the model i can call the residual value by:

```
model.resid
```

this method returns the residual value in the form of an array. You can also use this other method and visualize residual plots.

```
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

lm=smf.ols(formula ="var_y~var_x1+var_x2+var_x3",data=df).fit()
resid=lm.resid
plt.scatter(lm.predict(),resid)
```